# Btrfs snapshot as user is not permitted

Tags: linux, permissions, security, backup, btrfs

My backup user should be able to create a btrfs snapshot of the system subvolume (mounted at `/`). But this doesent work.

Setup: `subvol=/rootfs` is mounted on `/` and `subvol=/` is mounted on `/btrfs`

First:

```
root# mkdir /btrfs/backup && chown backup:backup /btrfs/backup
```

then as backup user:

```
backup$ btrfs subvol snapshot / /btrfs/backup/rootfs
Create a snapshot of '/' in '/btrfs/backup/rootfs'
ERROR: cannot snapshot '/': Operation not permitted
```

If I change the owner of `/` to be the backup user, it works, but is this the right way?

Ubuntu 16.04 / Linux 4.4.0-59-generic / btrfs-progs v4.4

Comment: Have you tried this on a current version (put a 6.1 kernel in a VM to test)?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I see that you make a directory, not a subvolume.

> btrfs subvolume create /path/to/the/location/…/subvolume-name

Secondly, the owner of a directory is different from a simple dir than a mount pont directory. In the second case, it's owned by root. So you must mount it and then, chown the directory mountpoint.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not really help me. I try to make a snapshot as user (not as root), which is not permitted even if the destination directory is owned by said user.